# Webpack setup for using less in nextJs for antd fails due to unexpected character

Tags: webpack, less, next.js, antd

I am using antd in my NextJS project and would like to customize the theme. So i am trying to update my `next.config.js` to do this. This is what I have done:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const lessToJS = require("less-vars-to-js");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config();

const themeVariables = lessToJS(
    fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/antd-custom.less"), "utf8")
);

module.exports = withLess({
    lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: themeVariables,
    },
    distDir: '../.next',
    webpack: config => {
        const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
            return acc;
        }, {});

        config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('./'));
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));

        return config;
    },
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
    },
});
```

However it seems to result with this when I start my dev server:

```
ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://err.sh/next.js/built-in-css-disabled

error - ./public/css/AppContainer.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> #root, html, body {
|     width: 100%;
|     height: 100%;
```

My `antd-custom.less` contains just this:

```
@primary-color: #1f5257;
```

Does anyone know what this means or how i can track down the issue?

I do have a `AppContainer.css` that has a `#` value for some things but not sure why that would be an issue?

Comment: Since Next.js built-in CSS support is disabled by adding `@zeit/next-less` plugin, you might need to add an appropriate loader for CSS (could try using `@zeit/next-css` plugin as well). Check this thread for more insights: https://github.com/vercel/next-plugins/issues/598

Comment: @juliomalves when I use the withCSS then i have the same issue but complaining about scss files.